# Display of json parser in tabular form in android app

Tags: android, json

I am new to Android and I got an assignment where I have to use JSON parser to parse the link and display the content in tabular form and its table field. When clicked, it should open some sections. Please, if anyone knows any kind of tutorial on how to do it, it would be really great. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Take a look at listviews, simply parse each row of your data into an ArrayList and pass this to a custom adaptor for your listview. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse the incoming data into POJO. It will be as simple as writing a class that matches your JSON data format.

Answer (score 0):

or just just the GSON framework from google

you will need to create a Pojo(or Bean) with basic constructor and fileds matching the name of the json String.

something like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(jsonProvider, new TypeToken<Contact>(){
    }.getType()
);
```

in this case the POJO is named Contact. After that u have an object filled with ur json data that u can use to do what ever u want...

hope this helps